# Unable to set single selection CheckBox using android:onClick=

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I'm attempting to set a single checkbox at a time as clicked using the following implementation :

[checkbox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPv8c.png)

```
public void itemClicked(View v) {
    //code to check if this checkbox is checked!
    for(int i=0 ; i < list.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
        {
            int position = list.getPositionForView(v);
            if(selectedIndex == position){
                list.setItemChecked(position, true);
            }
            else{
                list.setItemChecked(position, false);
            }
        }

}
```

...however all the checkboxes are checked and single selection is not working.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Full Source:

https://pastebin.com/sDXA00PZ
[checkbox][2]

CheckBox list.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution can be multiple . if you are using Custom adapter then do as following .

Make your `CheckBox` `android:clickable="false"` in list item xml. and set `CheckBox` state programatically only.

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:clickable="false"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

use a variable `int` for selected position .

```
private int selected ;
    public void setSelected(int selected){
        this.selected=selected;
     }
    public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Validate the selected position and set checked state here .

    }
```

Another simple solution can be .

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arr));
```